# ngx-dataTable How to apply format function

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-datatable

Data and .TS:

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  public allFruits = [
    { f: 1, detail: "Banana is good for health." },
    { f: 2, detail: "It is sweet." }
  ];

  fruitName = fruitS;

  public first10(n: string): string {
    return n.substring(0, 10);
  }

  colSpec = [
    { prop: "f", name: "fruit" }, // "fruitName[f]" or `${fruitName[f]}` won't work
    { prop: "detail" } // maybe need a pipe?
  ];
}

enum fruitS {
  Apple = 0,
  Banana,
  Melon
}
```

.HTML:

```
<b>PLAIN</b>
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let f of allFruits">
    <td>{{fruitName[f.f]}}</td>
    <td>|&nbsp;{{first10(f.detail)}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<b>ngx</b>
<ngx-datatable [rows]="allFruits" [columns]="colSpec">
</ngx-datatable>
```

Please see [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aed5rg?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: what errors do you see?

Comment: @StepUp Please see updated details and demo above, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really good place to find [demos of ngx-datatable](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#inline-edit).

It is necessary to use `ng-template` to apply formatting and other functions:

HTML:

```
<ngx-datatable 
  [rows]="allFruits" 
  class="material striped" 
  [columnMode]="'force'"  
  >
    <ngx-datatable-column name="f" headerClass="header">
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" 
          let-value="value" let-row="row">
         {{ fruitName[value] }}
      </ng-template>    
      </ngx-datatable-column>

    <ngx-datatable-column name="detail" headerClass="header">
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" 
          let-value="value" let-row="row">
        {{ first10(value)|uppercase }}
      </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

TypeScript:

```
 public allFruits = [
    { f: 0, detail: "Banana is good for health." },
    { f: 1, detail: "It is sweet." }
  ];

  fruitName = fruitS;

  public first10(n: string): string {
    return n.substring(0, 10);
  }

  public numToString(n: number): string {
    //alert(n);
    return this.fruitName[n];
  }
```

[The example can be seen here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-attlwa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Awesome example!

Comment: FYI, `pipe` and `transform` combined work too, please see my original demo. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jeb50 thank you, it is really useful information!

Comment: Fruit has many attributes, a wide table in database. For short and sortable fields such as country, origin place, I'd like to place them in top `<tr>`, then practically un-sortable, `ingredients: string[]`, `longDescription: string` would be in bottom `<tr>`. So each `fruit` will have 2 rows, and for the bottom row, Row Detail could be helpful to show partial or full info. I don't see API has `Row` object. Also will be great if we can do a fade-out effect on this row when it's in collapsed state.